# change the main menu color in asp menu

Tags: asp.net

I am using asp menu control.

I need to change the main menu color based on menu selection.

```
<asp:Menu ID="mMainMenus" DataSourceID="xmlDataSource" runat="server"   
DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" ForeColor="Black"   StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" StaticMenuItemStyle-Font-Bold="true" 
StaticDisplayLevels="1" StaticEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" DynamicEnableDefaultPopOutImage="false" Orientation="Horizontal"
Width="100%" >
<DataBindings>
    <asp:MenuItemBinding DataMember="MenuItem" NavigateUrlField="NavigateUrl" TextField="Text"
        ToolTipField="ToolTip"   />
</DataBindings>
```

i will change the selected  main menu color only o main menu selection change.
I need to change/highlight the main menu while clicking the sub menu. ie, change the color of active menu.

Thanks,

Pooja.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding different back colors to [Menu.StaticSelectedStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.staticselectedstyle.aspx) Property  and [Menu.DynamicSelectedStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.dynamicselectedstyle.aspx) Property

Comment: no it is not working. i need to change the main menu item while clicking the sub menu